# RDKit drawing problem: fingerprint graph didn't show up using Draw.DrawRDKitBit command

Tags: drawing, fingerprinting, rdkit

I simply copied and pasted these code from rdkit (https://www.rdkit.org/docs/GettingStartedInPython.html#generating-images-of-fingerprint-bits)
I was expecting to generate graphs.
However, I got a long string.

```
from rdkit import Chem 
from rdkit.Chem import AllChem
from rdkit.Chem import Draw
mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles('c1ccccc1CC1CC1')
bi = {}
fp = AllChem.GetMorganFingerprintAsBitVect(mol, radius=2, bitInfo=bi)
mfp2_svg = Draw.DrawMorganBit(mol, 872, bi)
rdkbi = {}
rdkfp = Chem.RDKFingerprint(mol, maxPath=5, bitInfo=rdkbi)
rdk_svg = Draw.DrawRDKitBit(mol, 1553, rdkbi)
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?
Thanks a lot in advanced.

I am now using python 3.6 and latest rdkit version (2018.09.1.0) on Windows

Comment: Welcome to SO. You may want to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Just add `from rdkit.Chem.Draw import IPythonConsole`

Answer (score 0):

To see depiction in IPython or Jupyter notebooks just add

```
from rdkit.Chem.Draw import IPythonConsole
```

The RDKit 'GettingStarted' did not use Ipython for the sample scripts, so the import of the IPythonConsole is never declared, allthough it is not new.

Look in the [RDKit Blog](https://rdkit.blogspot.com/) or search for notebooks the web and you see it is a standard.